# Background Images Stretched Out As I Add Content For Mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to add some background images to my web site, using the background property. I would like each image to take up the width and height of their container without being too pixlelated and still maintaing their aspect ratio. This is what I have so far.

Index.html

```
<!--Nav Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brand Image</a>
        </div><!-- ./navbar-header -->
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav><!--/.navbar End Of Nav Bar-->

<!-- Beginning of Site Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!--Each sectoin of the site is a column this is the row that holds all the columns -->
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Home Section -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 main-section home" id="home">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <h1>Title for the main header</h1>
                            <h2>Title for subheading</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <hr/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="padding-left : 15%; padding-right : 15%">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg social-links" href="#">Twitter</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3" >
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg social-links" href="#">Github</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg social-links" href="#" role="button">Linkedin</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg social-links" href="#" role="button">freeCodeCamp</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- ./ col-xs-12 main-section home -->

      <!-- About Section -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 main-section about" id="about">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <h2>Title of Subheading</h2>
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 side-pic">
                  <div class="img-container">
                    <img  src="images/dfann_picture.jpg" class="about-image"/>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.about--> 


  </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

main.css

```
    /*Styles The Sections Home, About, Portfolio, Contact */
    .main-section{
        padding: 10%;
        min-height:  850px;
        text-align : center;
        vertical-align : middle;
    }


/*Styles for the home section */
 /*For the contact buttons used*/
    .social-links{
        margin : 5px;
    }

    /*Jumbotron */
    .jumbotron{
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }    

    .home h1 {
            font-size : 4.5em;
            font-family: "Bitter";
            color : whitesmoke;
        }

    .home h2 {
        font-size : 2.5em;
        font-family: "Nunito";
        color : whitesmoke;
    }

    .home{
       background: #464646 url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oP9QfLUk4_YixVCz4fuKCpxkJ2LtR3g0YGoKtLYSA_vBQTO1YFHZfg2Iscj5hYF1vuSaHbF_QMSnoM6f_-XXYI9P47W5dKDafjeLJKEAa-dls_WjgKOZZEfdxCcZt1g_4uuGyxWdm5R6xQDV9ZQ1w6aDdWnhDLoofjJkNWUMNy3rV-hXIIKrY9T-81pN6kuhVY7uFxZYhOwo0hhvKr2e7ET5QnNy2PUO5T_FQ7TZKQWewkF7ljey6i_B1fnwoI8IBXtN0csoBPrV7kryK-PRUBbou3boG4ikPMU9NPLq1ljze5er0cKVvCWbtVhgbcNjg-B6emsSRvqHhqsZ7-WyQmMb4B4BOTohU9DJwfiVTv38boBYAgIKGCC_55pAZA9tb1nQ4oZbadxq02AfU_WkIqH21jltrOyf7sN2mK5VgTAT1fDP2r6D3yap0y-floTAvWtcrxeXWOmLiwZ7vNpIebLAkuq04yQcXPuscnU-J7VzaRBnCadoTt8BEgY3n2sNjeGwxIPLMnTKtZFDEUZBC77pRQ7ZwtgjPFcbxycwbVwD6IiBZxprdoV7F3Q65wpvR8EHyQ=w1343-h895-no) center center / cover no-repeat fixed; 
    }

/*End Styles for the home section*/

/*Styles for the about section*/

/*About Section Styles*/

    .about h1 {
        font-family: "Bitter";
        color : whitesmoke;
    }

    .about h2 {
        font-size : 4.5em;
        font-family: "Nunito";
        color : black;
    }

    .about p {
        font-size : 2.5em;

    }

    /*Background Image For Aboutscreen*/
    .about{
  background: #464646 url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/O1lxoFC8mNtnvpUIDL5VoX_smh8PV-1ZBER1KA9jcpGVkXYi72DJwHfW1Ehj2bMU9wl2LoKpSUee7EmyXxK57vPgWESE3XILTBGfEBj5wE1AXxFL4jYdBTAXbQg-X-Cdyzi3P5nrI5KRtQ57I6gbvst8sTRF-W79W1YPEQGkIRIcA_LPhz0-V1K6oqTd3o_jchKF5wxgTEDin9h5089wY94egqJbop0yeENb6mPrc44K3d5k-Z2ZXyq5MpJ-CDQG3gv0I6SKnJrlQe1cZXe3bB2KoRUaYfOors1937aaNRDe3UFPaCZgRkGm61NDoMyP0R0_b0zykjMfG--WnO6yo3JZqHBj9C-8HYi3dX4GBPS95gH61gmf58HA0ZJb-0ksjA6pzN4-rfIHyMCqH6reG6m5qyf6lKhrpCNUQCMWHLROxsmb30ImW4uS01uDZLUjljCY9q4arv17FaPaRqUTiov4DBxNk4PUxqBQDXxMWM8OjnPuVc-upRQmtbNCgkhB1wpYFSdFsEQ5ksKdnwZfamxYs2K7AQCkyg9BBKQqJcRCTWRfKTyhmeT0chWeAqw4HEmNfg=w1343-h895-no) center center / cover no-repeat fixed;     
    }

    /*Div holding about-image*/
    .img-container{
        overflow: auto;
        padding : 10% 0% 0% 0%;
    }

    /*Making abuot-image circular*/
    .about-image{
        padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
        float: left;
        border-radius : 50%;
        width : 50%
    }

    .h2{
        color: black;
    }

/*End About Section Styles
```

What I have now seems to be working they way I expect it too for PC's but when I look at the site on mobile. The images get more pixelated as I add more sections to my site.

[image: Site with Home and About sections]

If you remove the about section the image looks like how I would expect it to look.

[image: Site with just the home section]

How would I prevent the background image from getting more pixelated as I add more sections to my site?

Here's a link to the codepen I made for this http://codepen.io/dfann/pen/yeYRKP

Comment: does the codepen show the pixelation problem?

Comment: It does if you try to access the phone on mobile. I'm using safari on a iPhone 6+

Answer (score 0):

Usually i use background-size: cover; but if you really want to improve quality, use different image for responsive. Example:

```
.home{
   background: url("../img/image") center top no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .home{
      background: url("../img/image_for_mobile");
   }
}
```